# Flink TableAPI: Failed to Fetch

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-sql

I am playing around with the Flink tableAPI right now. I created a table, and want to see what's in the table. I thought if I use a SELECT statement with .collect(), I could get a iterator which I could use to iterate and see what's inside the table. But it's giving me the errors.

Code:

```
    public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {

        // initialize table environment
        StreamExecutionEnvironment bsEnv = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
        EnvironmentSettings bsSettings = EnvironmentSettings.newInstance().useBlinkPlanner().inStreamingMode().build();
        StreamTableEnvironment tableEnv = StreamTableEnvironment.create(bsEnv, bsSettings);

        // A table representing some machines
        tableEnv.executeSql("CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE machines(id INT) WITH ( 'connector' = 'kafka', " +
                "'topic' = 'quickstart-events', 'properties.bootstrap.servers' = 'localhost:9092', 'value.format' = 'json')");




        // Add four machines
        tableEnv.executeSql("INSERT INTO machines values(1)");
        tableEnv.executeSql("INSERT INTO machines values(3)");
        tableEnv.executeSql("INSERT INTO machines values(5)");
        tableEnv.executeSql("INSERT INTO machines values(8)");

        final CloseableIterator<Row> fetch = tableEnv.executeSql("SELECT id FROM machines").collect();

        while (fetch.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(fetch.next());
        }
}
```

Errors that I am getting:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to fetch next result
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.collect.CollectResultIterator.nextResultFromFetcher(CollectResultIterator.java:106)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.collect.CollectResultIterator.hasNext(CollectResultIterator.java:77)
    at org.apache.flink.table.planner.sinks.SelectTableSinkBase$RowIteratorWrapper.hasNext(SelectTableSinkBase.java:115)
    at org.apache.flink.table.api.internal.TableResultImpl$CloseableRowIteratorWrapper.hasNext(TableResultImpl.java:355)
    at com.vmware.dcm.examples.QuickStartWithTableAPI.main(QuickStartWithTableAPI.java:58)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to fetch job execution result
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.collect.CollectResultFetcher.getAccumulatorResults(CollectResultFetcher.java:175)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.collect.CollectResultFetcher.next(CollectResultFetcher.java:126)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.collect.CollectResultIterator.nextResultFromFetcher(CollectResultIterator.java:103)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to fetch job execution result

    ... 4 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobExecutionException: Job execution failed.
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.reportGet(CompletableFuture.java:395)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(CompletableFuture.java:2093)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobExecutionException: Job execution failed.

    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.collect.CollectResultFetcher.getAccumulatorResults(CollectResultFetcher.java:172)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobExecutionException: Job execution failed.
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.JobResult.toJobExecutionResult(JobResult.java:147)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.minicluster.MiniClusterJobClient.lambda$getJobExecutionResult$2(MiniClusterJobClient.java:119)
Caused by: org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobExecutionException: Job execution failed.

    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniApplyNow(CompletableFuture.java:680)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniApplyStage(CompletableFuture.java:658)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.thenApply(CompletableFuture.java:2165)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.minicluster.MiniClusterJobClient.getJobExecutionResult(MiniClusterJobClient.java:117)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: org.apache.flink.runtime.JobException: Recovery is suppressed by NoRestartBackoffTimeStrategy
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.failover.flip1.ExecutionFailureHandler.handleFailure(ExecutionFailureHandler.java:116)
Caused by: org.apache.flink.runtime.JobException: Recovery is suppressed by NoRestartBackoffTimeStrategy

    at org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.failover.flip1.ExecutionFailureHandler.getFailureHandlingResult(ExecutionFailureHandler.java:78)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.DefaultScheduler.handleTaskFailure(DefaultScheduler.java:224)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.DefaultScheduler.maybeHandleTaskFailure(DefaultScheduler.java:217)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.DefaultScheduler.updateTaskExecutionStateInternal(DefaultScheduler.java:208)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.SchedulerBase.updateTaskExecutionState(SchedulerBase.java:610)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.SchedulerNG.updateTaskExecutionState(SchedulerNG.java:89)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.JobMaster.updateTaskExecutionState(JobMaster.java:419)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor49.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.handleRpcInvocation(AkkaRpcActor.java:286)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.handleRpcMessage(AkkaRpcActor.java:201)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.FencedAkkaRpcActor.handleRpcMessage(FencedAkkaRpcActor.java:74)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.handleMessage(AkkaRpcActor.java:154)
    at akka.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.apply(CaseStatements.scala:26)
    at akka.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.apply(CaseStatements.scala:21)
    at scala.PartialFunction$class.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:123)
    at akka.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.applyOrElse(CaseStatements.scala:21)
    at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:170)
    at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:171)
    at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:171)
    at akka.actor.Actor$class.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:517)
    at akka.actor.AbstractActor.aroundReceive(AbstractActor.scala:225)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:592)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:561)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:258)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:225)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.exec(Mailbox.scala:235)
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timeout expired while fetching topic metadata
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timeout expired while fetching topic metadata
```

How should I fix this?